# prettier not working with JavaScript and CSS

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I've installed prettier in my code but it is not working in my javascript and CSS. I've also set the default formatter to prettier. but nothing happened. please tell me what's going on

Answer (score 1):

try adding this in settings.json

```json
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"[javascript]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: please check this as well only for javascript to false: `"[javascript]": {
"editor.formatOnSave": false 
}` and for auto-save config value to true `"editor.formatOnSave":true`

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I did :
Search for 'Prettier Path' in settings > select 'Edit in settings.json' and add the following config :

```
    {
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.fontSize": 12,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "[javascript]": {
    // "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true
  },
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "editor.columnSelection": false,
  "explorer.compactFolders": false,
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "prettier.prettierPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier"
}
```

Make sure prettier is installed at the given path : **"prettier.prettierPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier"**

You can make prettier the default also by uncommenting the code : **"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"**

It has my custom settings of visuals, so review those and then set, for beginners try pasting as-is!